# Making a video software editor in flash?

Tags: flash, video, editing

I am looking to make a video editing software in flash. The main thing I need help with right now is ***how to get media into a timeline***? and if you can expand on that it would be appreciated as well. But that is my main question, getting the media into a timeline and being able to move around the time of the video and have it display the media on a box

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is a bit vague and over-reaching - you may want to give the FAQ's a read-through and refocus your question into smaller, more focussed questions. Right now you're asking SO to basically design the whole architecture of your application, which is not feasible in a forum like this.

Comment: Hey, I wasn't really asking about how to make the entire program. I was asking how to create a timeline which you can add media to

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you asking for concepts here, rather than actual code, so here's some.

Conceptually, you need to create a "timeline" box object to represent an arbitrary length of time (pixels => milliseconds will be useful). Another box object to represent the length of your media; this box needs to be movable inside the other box horizontally. A playhead/cursor that can have a position in the timeline. You would then need to seek under the hood to the (timeline_cursor - media_start_time_in_timeline) in the media to display current frame.

Good luck!